# Add Icon to context Menu in VB.NET inside a windows forms appliction

Tags: vb.net, icons, contextmenu

I have searched many times here and on Google looking for a solution that did not envolve utilizing someone's class.

This context menu is pops up where the user right clicks inside a dataGridView

When adding the items the VB code is

```
Dim m As New ContextMenu()
m.MenuItems.Add(New MenuItem("Disassociate *A* Device"))
m.MenuItems.Add(New MenuItem("Purge Device Assosciations"))
```

Is there no simple way to reference a resource to add an icon to said menuItems?

Pseudo

```
m.MenuItem(0).Icon.Source = ....
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set [Owner Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.ownerdraw.aspx) to true and actually draw the menu item yourself

[Here is a good detailed example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5461/Working-with-OwnerDraw-Menus-in-VB-NET)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that this is for a Windows Forms application.

Why not use the ContextMenuStrip?

Example:

```
    Dim m As New ContextMenuStrip()

    Dim item As New ToolStripMenuItem("Click Me!")
    item.Image = My.Resources.image

    m.Items.Add(item)

    DataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = m
```

Comment: It is a ContextMenu(-Strip); your said properties do not seem to exist within this context. I think Micah is right...I'll keep looking for a simpler approach and resond if I find one.

Comment: You were using a ContextMenu, what I have above is a ContextMenuStrip they are different. This is what MSDN has to say: Although ContextMenuStrip replaces and adds functionality to the ContextMenu control of previous versions, ContextMenu is retained for both backward compatibility and future use if so desired.

Comment: This answer is better than Micah's as it uses built-in features of WinForms rather than relying on additional code to achieve its objective.

Answer (score 0):

I use the image propery and assign a system.drawing.image object to it.
You wont be able to do it in one line, you do the add once all the properties of the newmenu is set.